# Calculate lag difference in group

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to solve a problem using just SQL (I am able to do this when combining SQL and Python).

Basically what I want to do is to calculate score changes per candidate, where a score consists of joining a score lookup table and then summing these individual event scores. If a candidate fails, they are required to retake the events. Here is an example output:

```
| brandi_id | retest | total_score |
|-----------|--------|-------------|
| 1         | true   | 128         |
| 1         | false  | 234         |
| 2         | true   | 200         |
| 2         | false  | 230         |
| 3         | false  | 265         |
```

What I want is to first only calculate a score change for those candidates who took a retest, where the score change will just be the difference in total_score for retest is true minus retest = false:

```
| brandi_id | difference |
|-----------|------------|
| 1         | 106        |
| 2         | 30         |
```

This is the SQL that I am using (with this I need to use Python)

```sql
select e.brandi_id, e.retest, sum(sl.scaled_score) as total_score
from event as e
left join apf_score_lookup as sl
on sl.asmnt_code = e.asmnt_code
and sl.raw_score = e.score
where e.asmnt_code in ('APFPS','APFSU','APF2M')
group by e.brandi_id, e.retest
order by e.brandi_id;
```

I think the solution involves using LAG and PARTITION but I cannot get it. Thanks!

Comment: You just need o check the difference of the score?

Comment: The difference for `brandi_id = 1` is 106. How did you get 196?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant 106 @BalajiAmbresh

Comment: @JimMacaulay that is correct

Comment: What is your first table name?

Answer (score 1):

If someone does the retest only once, then you can use a join:

```
select tc.*, tr.score, (tc.score - tr.score) as diff
from t tc join
     t tr
     on tc.brandi_id = tr.brandi_id and
        tc.retest = 'true' and tr.retest = 'false';
```

You don't describe your table layout.  If the results are from the query in your question, you can just plug that in as a CTE.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I did not add adequate information in the question description, this is essentially the approach that we took, we had to join in another lookup table, I ended up handing this off to our SQL guy. Thanks though!